# How to use webrtc-adapter (adapter.js) shim in Webpack?

Tags: webpack

I have a commonjs browser application (typescript) that I use Webpack to bundle. It uses webrtc so I want to use the [webrtc-adapter package from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webrtc-adapter). It is the package for [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) which makes working with webrtc between firefox & chrome easier.

Inside my modules I want to be able to access the modified navigator item. For example, so I can simply call:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
```

I can get it to work if I require the package and then use the variable somewhere in my module like so:

```
var webrtc = require("webrtc-adapter");
// somewhere in module
console.log(webrtc.browserDetails);
```

However, I don't need to access browserDetails or any of the exposed items by webrtc-adapter, I just want to use the shimmed calls on the navigator object. I've tried using webpack.ProvidePlugin and externals but both still require that I use the object somewhere.

Is there a way I can load the shimmed navigator into each module without having to require and then use the variable somewhere in my modules? I know I can use external in the config and then load it via a separate script tag but I'd prefer to have webpack bundle it all together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried just requiring it like this?

`require('webrtc-adapter');`

Comment: This worked. Thanks. TypeScript outputs an error "Cannot find name require" if you do this. Adding `declare function require(moduleName: string)` fixed it though.

Answer (score 1):

For normal Webpack:

```ts
var a = require('webrtc-adapter');
```

For TypeScript. If you also want some typings, use the reference tag with @types/webrtc as well.

```ts
/// <reference types="webrtc" />
import 'webrtc-adapter';
```