# WebRTC Events in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, webrtc

I have a working WebRTC connection in Chrome. It uses 1 data channel as part of a chat application.

I want to also support Firefox thus I need to change some not supported events:
For the [RTCPeerConnection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection#Browser_compatibility) as well as for the [DataChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCDataChannel#Browser_compatibility).

The changes to the data channel worked as expected:

```
    //chrome implenetation
    dc.onopen = this.conncectionStats.bind(this);
    dc.onmessage = onMessage;
    // chrome and firefox
    dc.addEventListener('open', (event) => {
        this.conncectionStats.bind(this)
    });
    dc.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
        onMessage(event)
    });
```

However, the problem arises when changing the PeerConnection:

```
    // chrome implenetation
    pc.onconnectionstatechange  = this.onConnectionStateChange.bind(this);
    // chrome and firefox
    pc.addEventListener('onconnectionstatechange', (event) => {
        console.log("onconnectionstatechange fired")
        this.onConnectionStateChange.bind(this);
    })
```

The event is never occuring. Any ideas why this is the case?

The event should be [correct](https://www.w3.org/TR/webrtc/#dom-rtcpeerconnection-onconnectionstatechange), but on the other hand, the documentation is missing on [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/onconnectionstatechange).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use WebRTC adapter so that unsupported events will be shimmed for you:
https://github.com/webrtc/adapter

I am using it on my webpages, and onconnectionstatechange fires fine in Firefox:

```
...
pc.onconnectionstatechange = onConnStateChange;
...

function onConnStateChange(event) {
        if (pc.connectionState === "failed") {
            Terminate();
            alert("Connection failed; playback stopped");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using adapter.js [with html + js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37550395/10216108) or 
 [with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37122854/10216108)